# Is male circumcision without consent and without medical reason legal in France?

Tags: health, children

A lot of circumcision are realized on children in France without medical reasons.

Are those operations legal or illegal ?

Comment: With or without consent of the parents? Without this information this question is to general and cannot be answered properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Male circumcision is by default legal

In [France](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumcision_and_law) it requires the consent of both parents for children and the subject themselves if an adult.

If performed for religious or cultural reasons the risks must be explained. If performed for medical reasons, all alternate therapies must be explained as well.